# "There is no" or "There is no other"

Tags: transatlantic-differences

There is no mountain in Myanmar as high as Mt. Everest.
or
There is no other mountain in Myanmar as high as Mt. Everest
What are the differences in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: This was just asked earlier today, perhaps by someone you know?

Comment: This a strange statement to make. It implies that there might be a mountain in some other country higher than Everest, but Everest is the highest mountain **in the world**.

Comment: Then, I want to know the difference between " There is no bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park." and "There is no other bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***There is no mountain in Myanmar as high as Mt. Everest.*** doesn't say or suggest anything about the location of Mt. Everest; it merely says that Mt. Everest is higher than any mountain in Myanmar.

***There is no other mountain in Myanmar as high as Mt. Everest.*** implicitly suggests that Mt. Everest is in Myanmar (it's not; it's in Nepal), and it is the highest mountain in that country.

This is not a difference in BrE vs AmE; the [transatlantic-differences](/questions/tagged/transatlantic-differences) tag is inappropriate.

Comment: +1 -- but Everest is not entirely in Nepal: it lies on the border between Nepal and China.

Comment: @StoneyB - conceded, but either way, it's nowhere near Myanmar.

Comment: Then, I want to know the difference between " There is no bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park." and "There is no other bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park".

Comment: Same thing. If Jurong Bird Park is in Southeast Asia then there is **no other** bird park as large. If that park is somewhere else, then there is **no** bird park in Southeast Asia as large.

Comment: So, Weather Vane , Do you mean that if we don't know the location  of Jurong Bird Park, we should say that there is no other bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park?

Comment: No, the other way round. If you don't know where XYZ park is, then there is no park in SE Asia as big, but the whole thing, as I said in my comment under the question, is contrived — you don't know where the highest, biggest, whatever is? That's unreal.